# object references an unsaved transient instance : save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities: PlayerProfileEntity & UserInfoEntity
I have a join on userInfoEntity & PlaterProfileEntity and saving my record in database like this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(PlayerProfileEntity.class);
player.setUserId(new UserInfoEntity());
player.getUserId().setAddress(user.getUserId().getAddress());
session.save(player);
tr.commit();
```

I used this assosiation in my PlayerProfileEntity class

```
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="userid")
```

I am getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save     the transient instance before flushing: com.shared.entity.UserInfoEntity
```

Note : If i use CascadeType.All, i get this error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Any idea how can i solve this

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `TransientObjectException` comes whenever you try to save the Object without saving the appropriate Joins.You have to save the `UserInfoEntity` first and afterwards you can save your `PlayerInfoEntity` class.

```
player.setUserId(new UserInfoEntity());
```

By using this you are assigning particular `UserInfoEntity` to `PlayerInfoEntity`. But `UserInfoEntity` does not have any ID. How would both get mapped ? That is why the exception is coming.

Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL

Comment: thanks , but i am already using CascadeType.ALL, as mentioned in my question and get the error : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails , any idea on that

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't see the note in the end. I think, though, we should concentrate on that error you get with CascadeType.ALL.

Comment: You show a line involving `Criteria`, but it's irrelevant to your code. On the other hand, it's missing important code that assembles the `Player` you are going to save. Also, this line is confusing me: `player.getUserId().setAddress(user.getUserId().getAddress())` What's the point of that? And how come UserId is a composite object?

Comment: If `user` is a persistent object, then his `address` is also persistent. You set that address to the non-persistent object `player`. This could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: thanks , i guess this would be a beginner question , but how player is a non persistent object and how could i make the object player persistent ? thanks

Comment: It's about the current state of the object as perceived by Hibernate. When you say `session.save(o)`, it's implicitly doing `session.persist(o)` before saving. You can call it yourself, too. At that point Hibernate will "take notice" of your object and enroll it into the session.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void savePlayerMethod(PlayerInfoEntity player){

if(player == null){
   player = new PlayerInfoEntity();
}
player.setUserId(getSavedUserInfo());
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(userInfo);
transaction.committ();
}

public UserInfoEntity getSavedUserInfo(){
UserInfoEntity userInfo = new UserInfoEntity();
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(userInfo);
transaction.committ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error just now, when trying to store an unsaved object that had an assigned ID through the Session#save() method. I think the problem might be that your unsaved object graph has already been given an id (which is something that the save-method tries to do), and this somehow messes up the cascade of the save-method. Try using Session#persist() instead, cascade should work with this, even though the object has already been assigned an id.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, after lots of debugging i found that removing @AllArgsConstructor from entity and adding

```
@Tolerate
public <ClassName>() {
}
```

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Well,

I had simmilar problem and what I did was

```
Object tmp = session.get(Object.class,ob.getId())
if(tmp!=null){
    session.evit(tmp); // or merge
}
session.saveOrUpdate(ob);
```

This worked for me.

It gets the transient object and evicts it or merges it.

Now use save or update method to save your new object.

Comment: You need to explain more about this solution.  How does evicting then saving solve this problem.  Typically this problem is caused by *not* saving an entity attached to the current one being saved.